# python - How to speed up boolean expression evaluation

Tags: python, logical-operators

In java you can speed up execution of the boolean expression if using a double operand like `&&` or `||`.

Is there anything like this in python?

Clarification for those unfamiliar with Java: When I have a logical Java expression consisting of several parts, e.g. `p & q & r`, at runtime JRE will have to evaluate every part to get the result. If I am writing this as `p && q && r`, and say my `p` is false, JRE will stop evaluating the whole expression before reaching `q` and will return False.

Comment: That's called "short circuiting" btw. And, it should be noted that that's not the main difference between `&` and `&&`. `&` is bitwise AND, `&&` is logical AND.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The behavior you describe after "Clarification for those unfamiliar with Java:" is known as "short circuiting". The link I posted answers your question.